# Can knowing a custom Facebook URL of someone bypass "who can look up my timeline by name" privacy option?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline

I have a Facebook profile with a custom URL name. For example Catdog:  `www.facebook.com/Catdog`.

So does that mean if someone enters: `www.facebook.com/Catdog` into their browser AND they are not my friend OR mutual friend, could still see my Timeline even though I've set "ONLY FRIENDS" in the "Who could look up my Timeline by name" options in the privacy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your privacy settings apply even to customized URLs for your Facebook profile.

There is always going to be some public information provided when people visit your profile page (Profile pic, basic info unless hidden). If you'd like to see what the public sees when visiting your profile, go to the Settings gear box on your Timeline and select "View as..."

The default view will show you how you appear to the public, as well as provide a box for you to see how your various friends see your profile as well.

Comment: so that means, someone I don't know, with my custom URL will be able to see my timeline? so there's no way to hide my timeline from public except for friends is that right to say? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately yes, someone with the exact profile URL will be able to see that you are on Facebook. They will see a public profile pic, unless you set a pic to not show your face? The only way to prevent someone with the direct URL from seeing anything is to deactivate the account.

Comment: I see. thank you so much for clearing that up for me. Ugh I sometimes hate how Facebook works. I'm only still on there just for keeping in touch with classmates and friends all spread across the globe. :(